# TeamCity JMeter plugin not showing remote monitoring

Tags: jmeter, teamcity

I've followed [this guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-jmeter-tests-teamcity-continuous-integration) to have my TeamCity build running some JMeter tests, but I'm not seeing the "RemotePerfMon" tab for the server statistics. I have the "Performance Statistics" tab, and I can see that the statistics are definitely being collected, as there is a `monitoring.csv` file being created and populated in the build agent's work directory.

Any ideas on how I can get the tab to display?

I'm using TeamCity v9.1.6 with JMeter plugin version 83, everything running on Windows 8.

*Additional Info:*
I've found that there is an [open issue on Github](https://github.com/jtorgan/jmeter_plugin/issues/14) for this problem, so I'm obviously not the only one facing this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make sure TeamCity is NOT running as Administrator**

After quite a while playing around with it, I discovered that the problem was that both the TeamCity Server and the TeamCity build agent were running on the same machine, but the Build agent was running as Administrator. Stopping both the services and restarting them as a regular user fixed the issue.

I believe the root of the issue was that the `monitoring.csv` file was created by the Build Agent as Administrator, then wen the non-admin server agent attempted to parse it, it failed. This error doesn't seem to get logged anywhere, and TeamCity responds to the error by simply not displaying the tab.